# Parsing Invalid JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

because hardware limitation I need to parse invalid JSON formats. With NSJSONSerialization if the JSON is invalid or if have some special characters returns nil. For example

```
{ 
"/http/header":"
    {\"code\":\"200\", 
    \"response\":\"The request has succeeded\",
    \"body\":\H4؊捵ե7Ǫ㖮OƋ\"V鈭핬Ͱ枥ù޷+=豞EA㯕頎̵4kև΃
ΆץmZ-\"뺷뀕ԍ볰孖擽o<ҲA혃褿Уҥx蒊㟩g=Ң흨׮4YhkeȤ̪⤍βQ
䷹!긗Â㍡Զ䧡|jŔ䴕uA蝓蒎▖嗷н骭--̫Tʴͽ"}
}
```

This is a wrong JSON format but if we correct the format of this JSON the problem persists because we have special characters. 
Gson on JAVA with this kind of JSON code don't have any problem, I can get the code and response value the only nil value is the body. There are someway to have the values?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to correct the json format? Because the json values must not contain line breaks.

The valid json should look like this:

```
{
   "/http/header":{
     "code":"200",
     "response":"The request has succeeded",
     "body":"H4؊捵ե7Ǫ㖮OƋ\"V鈭핬Ͱ枥ù޷+=豞EA㯕頎̵4kև΃ΆץmZ-\"뺷뀕ԍ볰孖擽o<ҲA혃褿Уҥx蒊㟩g=Ң흨׮4YhkeȤ̪⤍βQ䷹!긗Â㍡Զ䧡|jŔ䴕uA蝓蒎▖嗷н骭--̫Tʴͽ"
   }
}
```

So you can replace all line breaks and unnecessary backslashes

Comment: The result still nil using `NSJSONSerialization`. Because the special characters. GSON give in Java a hash with code and response value, only body have a null value.

Answer (score 0):

To check your JSON valid or invalid use : http://pro.jsonlint.com/

```
{
    "/http/header": {
        "code": "200",
        "response": "The request has succeeded",
        "body": "H4؊捵ե7Ǫ㖮OƋ\"V鈭핬Ͱ枥ù޷+=豞EA㯕頎̵4kև΃ΆץmZ-\"뺷뀕ԍ볰孖擽o<ҲA혃褿Уҥx蒊㟩g=Ң흨׮4YhkeȤ̪⤍βQ䷹!긗Â㍡Զ䧡|jŔ䴕uA蝓蒎▖嗷н骭--̫Tʴͽ"
    }
}
```

Comment: But what I want is to work with a invalid Json. And NSJSONSerialization don't accept Chinese characters. I can manually remove the breaks but I continue with the same problem.